# ESXI Web UI not letting me login

Tags: vmware-esxi

The ESXI 6.7 UI is not allowing me to login from any pc or browser. I am using the correct credentials. The only thing it does is says, "Please refresh your browser" underneath the vmware esxi logo. As mentioned, its been working well for months and this is the first time its done this.
I don't have SSH enabled.

Answer (score 0):

Since the error reference you have it looks is only a portion, it's difficult to say.

The most likely culprit is the change in Flash and Flash permissions. Chrome has flash disabled by Default. Can you try Firefox and internet explorer and report if those also fail? Assuming you made no recent ESXi changes, the browser not working in the flash version makes sense.

If it's only the HTMl5 ESXi UI that is failing, the next step is to ensure you're up to date on ESXi [similar issues reported here](https://communities.vmware.com/thread/542973) . Since you mentioned SSH is not enabled, you'll have to enable SSH and that is described [here](http://www.virtubytes.com/2017/04/21/enable-ssh-vmware-esxi-6-5/)

If the ESXi is up to date, each browser is experiencing the same issue,